# type of request body for expressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know what kind of content type does request `req` in `app.post('/',function(req,res))` support. I am sending data from HTML form. Should it necessarily be in JSON format or is it possible to send directly from form?

I have sent json format data from the form to server but when I access `req.body.{name attribute of inout element}` it gives error invalid property of undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Express supports both formats. However, before it can work, you do need to use the `bodyParser` middleware, otherwise `req.body` will not be populated:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Here's a minimal app with accepts both form and json data posted to it:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
  res.send('You submitted: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
});

app.listen(3012);
```

You need to make sure that the `bodyParser` middleware is loaded *before* your routes, otherwise requests to your routes will not be handled by the `bodyParser` middleware first and your route-handler won't be able to use `req.body`.

Comment: I have also added that piece of code but still it does not work

Comment: I added an example to my answer.