# How to send data from the front end to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server, backend

This is my first time dealing with databases and im really facing some difficulties and hope someone can help me out.

Im trying to send data from the front-end(react js) to the back-end(node js) and then to mongodb database (so it would be saved there). I called the server succefully with the data, but Im not able to send the date to the database from the server. These are my files.

react js file: ( this function is called when the user enters some text and clicks on a button )

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("its running");
    let databody = {
      message: this.state.val,
    };
    console.log(" the message is :" + this.state.val);
    return fetch("http://localhost:5000/stored", {
      method: "POST",
      body: databody,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  };
```

index.js/server file: ( here is where im getting my error which says that db is not defined, honestly i get it but i dont know what am i supposed to define it as, and will my problem be solved the data be sent if i define it the right way?)

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors"); // Importing cors
var request = require("request");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const port = 5000;
var request = require("request");
var util = require("util");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
connectDB();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hey there!");
});

app.get("/Pinged", function (req, res) {
  find_my_iphone();
  res.send("Pinged!");
});

app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));

app.post("/stored", (req, res) => {
  console.log("its running 2: " + req.body);
  db.collection("quotes").insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send("saved to db: " + data);
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

db.js file inside config folder:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      // useCreateIndex: true,
      // useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected : ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Convert `req.body` to JSON before inserting ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364817/type-of-request-body-for-expressjs)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are doing couple of things wrong here.

First change your `db.js` file and make it return the connection instance.

Change it to this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected : ${conn.connection.host}`);
    
    return conn;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Second, Now you can use the db in your `index.js/server` file.
Change you `index.js/server` file to this

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors"); // Importing cors
var request = require("request");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const port = 5000;
var request = require("request");
var util = require("util");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
const db = connectDB();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hey there!");
});

app.get("/Pinged", function (req, res) {
  find_my_iphone();
  res.send("Pinged!");
});

app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));

app.post("/stored", (req, res) => {
  console.log("its running 2: " + req.body);
  db.collection("quotes").insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send("saved to db: " + data);
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Hello Khalid,  Thank you so much for your answer. When i did the changes I got aan error saying db.collection is not a function. Do you know why?

Comment: Actually you should be creating a schema for communicating with database. or else use your connectDB method with await keyword